# Using ddply on dataframe with dates in POSIXlt time

Tags: r, plyr

The problem:

You have a data.frame (df) that consists of some columns of the POSIXlt date format.

Output of str(df) is following:

`$identifier   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $date.time    : POSIXlt, format: "2010-06-01 07:27:00" "2010-06-01 07:27:00"`

If you use

`ddply(df, identifier, summarise, min.time = min(date.tim)`

You will get a similar error:

`'names' attribute [11] must be the same length as the vector [10]`

Solution mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is documented [in this github issue](https://github.com/hadley/plyr/issues/132)

It is basically a dataframe's inability to handle POSIXlt date.

> "POSIXct" is more convenient for including in data frames, and
>   "POSIXlt" is closer to human-readable forms.

The solution mentioned in the issue is the following

```
df$tm <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(dates, times), "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"))
ddply(df, ~Var1, dim)
```